# SIR stratified by attained age with popEpi package

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate SIRs by attained age using the popEpi package and I would like to stratify results by attained age (0-5; 5-10;10-15 ... 60-65; 65+).
I cannot figure out how to get this done. For stratifying results by follow-up time, I used the following syntax:

```
c <- lexpand( DatasetSMN, status = status, birth = bi_date, exit = ex_date, entry = dg_date,
               breaks = list(per = 1960:2013, age = 1:100, fot = c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,Inf)), 
               aggre = list(fot, agegroup = age, year = per, sex) )

se <- sir( coh.data = c, coh.obs = 'from0to1', coh.pyrs = 'pyrs',
           ref.data = incdata, ref.rate = 'value', conf.type = "univariate", 
           adjust = c('agegroup','year','sex'), print ='fot')
```

This works, but I don't know how to adapt this to get results stratified by attained age.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to stratify output by attained age as follows:

```
update(se, print = list(agegroup))
```

It is also possible to make this across multiple variables by doing:

```
update(se, print = list(sex, agegroup))
```

Or it is even possible to do a little differently:

```
update(se, print = list(age.cat = cut(agegroup, c(0,50,75,100), dig.lab=4)))
```